# rails won't switch to production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, passenger, production, bluehost

I have a site hosted on Bluehost that works when in development environment. I have been having troublle getting it to work in production and that is another issue. I am trying to switch back to production mode. I changed .htaccess

```
...
RailsEnv = production
...
```

I ran

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

I even tried

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

But it stays in development!!

```
rake about 
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.3 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          1.8.23
Rack version              1.5
Rails version             4.0.0
JavaScript Runtime        therubyracer (V8)
Active Record version     4.0.0
Action Pack version       4.0.0
Action Mailer version     4.0.0
Active Support version    4.0.0
Middleware                ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000000045894c8>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag
Application root          /home3/*****/rails_apps/my_site
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql2
Database schema version   20140910132221
```

log/production.log file size is not changing.

config/environments.rb

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home3/<username>/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.3'
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MySite::Application.initialize!
```

In config/environments/production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

If I set it to true the site won't come up at all

Comment: show please what inside `config/environments`?

Comment: Does that mean that when you’re running `rake ..`, it’s not running migrations against production database (as configured in `db/config.yml`)? I’d guess your `Rakefile` is broken in that case.

Comment: I apologize for not answering you question directly, but my solution would be to drop Bluehost as a provider. In addition to issues like this, their claim of "unlimited hosting space and file transfers" will quickly become apparent as a lie once your site  hits even moderate scale or complexity. Think they would host twitter for $4 a month? I am an ex-customer that they screwed over, so take my complaints with a grain of salt (when I left, I promised them I would advertise negatively for them whenever I found the opportunity). There are too many good providers to mess around with those idiots.

Comment: Yes rake is running migrations against the dev db

Comment: I've been thinking the same thing. It has been a total nightmare. Every step of the way has been torture.

Comment: Related link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162144/what-are-the-good-ruby-on-rails-hosting-service-out-there (off-topic, but some good info).